# How to replace a string which starts and ends with a set of "special" characters (tags)

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a Firebird 3.x text blob with text like this:

```
This is an {START example a=b}. The {duck} is big.
```

I want to replace all `{START _____}` with `(#_____#)`. At the position of the `_____` should be the text that is between "{START " and "}". In this example the result would be:

```
This is an (#example a=b#). The {duck} is big.
```

Note that the closing parenthesis after "duck" must not be replaced, because there is no "{START " before "duck".

How to do this?

Comment: When START is present in the text blob, is the closing `  } ` always followed by a ` . `?

Comment: The closing } is just the } alone.  No dot or something else.

Comment: I get that, but was wondering if that's a pattern we could capitalize on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like this are possible in Firebird, but are a bit convoluted to do. You might want to consider doing this in your programming language of choice.

In Firebird, you can use [`POSITION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-position) to find the start and end marker, and then use [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) and concatenation to rebuild the string.

Using these functions, you can build your own [PSQL function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql):

```sql
create or alter function replace_tags(input_value blob sub_type text) returns blob sub_type text
as
declare temp blob sub_type text = '';
declare start_tag char(7) = '{START ';
declare end_tag char(1) = '}';
declare start_replacement char(2) = '(#';
declare end_replacement char(2) = '#)';
declare search_start integer = 1;
declare start_position integer;
declare end_position integer;
begin
    while (true) do
    begin
        -- Search for occurrence of start-tag '{START ' 
        start_position = position(start_tag, input_value, search_start);
        if (start_position = 0) then leave;
    
        -- Search for occurrence of end-tag '}' after start-tag
        end_position = position(end_tag, input_value, start_position + 7);
        if (end_position = 0) then leave;

        temp = temp
             -- Add text before start-tag (and after previous end-tag found)
             || substring(input_value from search_start for start_position - search_start)
             -- Add replacement start-tag
             || start_replacement
             -- Add text between start-tag and end-tag
             || substring(input_value from start_position + 7 for end_position - start_position - 7)
             -- Add replacement end-tag
             || end_replacement;

        -- Setup for next search or finding remainder of string
        search_start = end_position + 1;
    end
    -- Add remainder of the string
    temp = temp || substring(input_value from search_start);
    return temp;
end
```

I did not fully test this function, so make sure to test it yourself.

Example of usage:

```sql
select replace_tags('This is an {START example a=b}. The {duck} is big.')
from rdb$database
```

Output:

```
This is an (#example a=b#). The {duck} is big.
```

Comment: Thank you Mark! I will try it. I thought there could be an easy way like a regex replace function or something like that.

Comment: @TomCat500 Unfortunately a regex-based replace function is not (yet) available in Firebird.

Comment: Now I've tested it: It works perfectly! Thanks again.